# Can I omit 「の」and 「もの」in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

Here is the sentence.

新聞で**の**寄付金詐欺をやったとき十万円**もの**大金を寄付した人がいただろう。

Removing them, does the meaning of the sentence change as much?

Comment: You changed your question after I posted an answer.

Comment: @l'électeur  Yes, I would like to ask more about removing the 「もの」too.
Sorry, if I made the mistake in editing the question in improper way.

Comment: @George It looks like it worked out okay this time because the answerer was willing to edit.  In the future, though, you should probably ask your new question separately instead of editing.  In general, edits should try to avoid invalidating any existing answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Can I omit「の」?**

Yes. If you do so, the sentence structure (← grammar) will change but the meaning will be retained almost completely.

> 「[新聞]{しんぶん}**での**[寄付金詐欺]{きふきんさぎ}をやったとき、[十万円]{じゅうまんえん}もの[大金]{たいきん}を[寄付]{きふ}した人がいただろう。」

Here, 「新聞**での**」 modifies 「寄付金詐欺」.　「新聞**での**」functions ***adjectivally***.

> 「新聞**で**寄付金詐欺をやったとき、十万円もの大金を寄付した人がいただろう。」

In this sentence, 「新聞**で**」 modifies 「やった」.  「新聞**で**」 functions ***adverbially***.

Both sentences are grammatical and natural-sounding.  They practically have the same meaning as well.

**Can I omit「もの」?**

No. You cannot omit the 「もの」 in 「十万円もの大金」 because you cannot say 「十万円大金」.  If you used 「という」 instead of 「もの」, it would at least be a grammatical phrase, but 「もの」 will express the surprise much better.

---

***For learners interested in pitch accents, this 「もの」 is pronounced differently than 「もの」 meaning "thing".  The pitch accent is on the 「も」 in this 「もの」.  It is on the 「の」 in  「[物]{もの}」 and 「[者]{もの}」.

Comment: Thanks for your description. Could you please tell me if I can remove the 「もの」as well?

Comment: What if you use 十万円 adverbially? Though it's still unnatural to be combined with 大金 instead of just 金...